# SVN - Commit via VIM - Recover failed commit message

Tags: linux, svn, vim, version, vi

I typically use VIM for almost everything coding-related.

I have configured my environment so Subversion opens VIM to edit the commit message when I execute `svn commit`. If I close VIM without saving the commit message (eg: `:qa!`), it is discarded, and the commit operation is aborted.

If I save and close VIM, then the commit operation will commence.

If the commit fails, I have some SVN commit messages that appear to be saved in /tmp/ with file names like svn-******.tmp.

While writing the commit message in VIM, the commit message appears to have a file name of svn-commit.1.tmp. I would like to be able to recover this message for my next SVN commit. The typically use case is:

1. I attempt to commit; complete writing message in VIM
2. Commit fails
3. I resolve the issue (eg: `svn update`)
4. Now I want to attempt `svn commit` again with the previous message pre-loaded into VIM

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use the `-F` option with svn commit, which uses a file to create the log message.

Whenever I commit with svn, I first create a log file:

```
vim log_file
```

Then I use the following to commit:

```
svn commit -F log_file --username blah
```

This has always worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this: 
`svn commit -F /tmp/svn-1.tmp`
You can read more there: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re06.html

Answer (score 1):

When in your vim session, just read the contents of the old log file.  This permits you to adapt the old message if necessary, and doesn't change the workflow radically.

```
svn commit
```

(opens vim session)

```
:r /tmp/svn-**.tmp
```

Another solution is to just do your commits from the command line with the `-m` flag.  This typically has the last (failed) commit in the command history of the related shell.

```
svn commit -m "Here is my message"
```

(commit fails, and you resolve it)

(up arrow a few times, and rerun the commit)

Answer (score 0):

Git will store a cached version of your commit message in `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`.

After a "failed" committing attempt, you could run the following to recover your commit message.

```
vim .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133526/git-recover-failed-commits-message