# Git commit messages lost by vi

Tags: git, vim

I'm a clumsy typist, and I don't use vi/vim very often, but I do use it for commit messages. However, if you type a wrong command while editing a commit message (`:Wq`, say, instead of `:wq`), when you correctly close out the commit message in vim with `:wq` or `:x`, you get this:

```
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Normally, a wrong command like `:W` is no problem—vim just ignores it and you can keep on working with the file and save it, but in git commit messages as soon as I mistype, I have irrevocably lost the commit message.

What's going on here, and how do I fix it? (Using git 1.9.1 via homebrew, vim 7.3 as packaged with OS X 10.9)

Comment: My solution to this and other problems is and has always been switching to `nano`.

Comment: While others may answer your exact question, a tip to share:  In my version of git on macOS (installed by XCode), I can recover the "lost" commit message by looking in the repo's .git directory for the COMMIT_EDITMSG file.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should set vim to not detach from the shell and be in the foreground. You can do this with the following command:

```
git config --global core.editor vim -f
```

From the man:

```
   -f          Foreground.  For the GUI version, Vim will not fork and detach from the shell it
               was  started in.  On the Amiga, Vim is not restarted to open a new window.  This
               option should be used when Vim is executed by a program that will wait  for  the
               edit  session  to  finish (e.g. mail).  On the Amiga the ":sh" and ":!" commands
               will not work.
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this could work without quoting the value. I think the last bit should be quoted: `"vim -f"`

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```sh
git config --global core.editor vim
```

I think this is the difference between Vim and Vi (although `vi` on most platform is actually Vim running in compatibility mode). Note that Git uses `vi` by default, which you can tell from [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var#Documentation/git-var.txt-GITEDITOR):

> The order of preference is the `$GIT_EDITOR` environment variable, then `core.editor` configuration, then `$VISUAL`, then `$EDITOR`, and then the default chosen at compile time, which is usually `vi`.

On my machine (macOS) the full path doesn’t make any difference (which is expected); `vim` is the same as `/usr/bin/vim`, and `vi` is the same as `/usr/bin/vi`.

Note: you can also tell the program from the error message:

```
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
```

The quoted `vi` is exactly the command for your editor. You can verify that with

```sh
GIT_EDITOR='false -a -b' git commit
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in several posts vim is exiting with a exit code other than zero. You can fix it by explicitely setting the git editor to the full vim path:

```
git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim
```

If I remember correctly I fixed the issue by installing a homebrewed vim. Make sure your path is set correctly then.

Comment: I actually just checked this - open vim, entered a wrong command, then correctly entered `:wq`, and checked the exit code (`echo $?`), and the exit code was 0.